# Allow credentials external post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, csrf

Good evening I have a problem with a functionality with **Devise** that I am implementing, I am receiving a parameter by URL that comes from an external request in another application, but when my application captures this request it is blocked since by default Rails or Devise block requests external post, what I did was disable this validation with "**skip_before_action: verify_authenticity_token**" but with this my application is vulnerable to a **CSRF attack**, I need to find a way to allow this request without making my application vulnerable.

One idea I had was to implement "**add_allow_credentials_headers**" but I do not know if it can be done or how to do it well

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4QpL.png)

[ExternalPostRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pqOR.png)

[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgy4f.png)

[Method_In_Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n02pl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 options:

- Creating a login API (100% working).
- render the login form => append it to an external website. I have never done this yet. But you can try it.